# Marketing Cloud REST API to Find Recently-Modified Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm working with the SFMC REST API. My goal is to return basic contact information (first and last name, email, phone, etc) about any/all contacts that have been modified after a particular date and time.

Basically, this example [from the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/searchSchema.htm)...

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /contacts/v1/contacts/search
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Email Demographics.Favorite Color",
                "id": "",
                    "isCustomerData": false
            },
                "operator": "Equals",
                "value": {
                    "items": ["Blue"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Except:

- Search by last updated/modified date, instead of by favorite color
- Return full name and contact info, instead of / in addition to just "contactKey" and "contactID"

How should I modify the request body in the example above to achieve this?

Comment: This example is retrieving Subscriber Profile Attributes. Are you storing your contact information as Profile Attributes (in All Subscribers list) or is this stored in Data Extensions? If you can advise, I can provide a sample payload for you to use.

Comment: @eliot-harper - hmm, I don't know! This is my first time working with SFMC, let alone creating an API integration for it, so based on the type of info I'm trying to retrieve, I just assumed the Contacts endpoint is what I should be querying. But if Data Extensions is the other possibility, would you mind pointing me to the relevant REST API documentation for it, or to a basic example? So far I've been unable to find either. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Contacts Search method to return any Contact Attribute that exists in your contact model. You need to review [Contact Builder](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/getting_started_with_contact_builder/) and configure your contact model before you can use this method.